# "cannot find Chrome binary error" when running Selenium chrome driver in a Google Cloud instance (on jupyter Lab)

Tags: selenium, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver, jupyter-lab

I'm using a Jupyter Lab notebook which run on google cloud instance. After I installed chromedriver using the following command line:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/85.0.4183.87/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

then I unzip it with:

```
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

After which I run the following cell:

```
from selenium import webdriver

path = '/home/jupyter/chromedriver' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

And this is where I get the error :  `WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary` (I'm pretty sure the path to Chromedriver is right though)

This work perfectly on my local machine but I'm a bit lost as to why I can't have it work on a Google Cloud instance. Can you please help me out with this issue ? (Also I have tried other things by looking at other posts online but without success). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://medium.com/@shanyitan/how-to-install-selenium-and-run-it-successfully-via-jupyter-lab-c3f50d22a0d4) is an example on how to install Selenium on a Jupyter notebook.

It is recommended to install it wit pip:

```
!pip install selenium
```

and to import os and sys:

```
import os
import sys
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```